# Do projections on $\mathbb{R}^2$ transform straight lines to straight lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

A linear transformation $P:\mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is called projection if      $P \circ P =P$.

The question is: If $P$  is a projection then $P$  transforms  straight lines in straight lines.

My idea was to replace $y$ for $mx +b$ and calculate $P$ for these values and see if the result was a straight but could not, then I thought it was fake but i know how to construct a counterexample.

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia page on [projective geometry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry) of interest...

Comment: think about the projection of vertical lines onto the $x$-axis. That is define $P(x,y)=(x,0)$ and think about $x=a$ projecting to $(a,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A projection can also take a straight line to a point.  For example, take
$$
P(x,y) = (0,y)
$$
and consider the line $y = 2$.

In general, we can write any line in $\Bbb R^2$ as
$$
L = \{v_1 + t v_2: t \in \Bbb R\}
$$
for some vector (i.e. point on the line) $v_1$ and vector $v_2$.  We can then write
$$
P(v_1 + tv_2) = P(v_1) + tP(v_2)
$$
This means that $P(L)$ will give us a line when $P(v_2) \neq 0$ and a point otherwise.

A linear transformation will take straight lines to straight lines if and only if it is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite true.  All linear transformations transform straight lines to either straight lines or points.   Just note that $T({\bf a} + t{\bf b}) = T{\bf a} + t T{\bf b}$.  You get a point if $T{\bf b} = 0$, and this is quite possible for a projection.